# Stored Procedure fit in

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

How can I call a stored procedure in the following code instead if the sqlcommand statement,

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Function GetPtPrt() As String
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TblRegjoin.PrtFilenum, TblReg.Fname + ' ' + TblReg.Sname + ' ' + TblReg.Lname, PrtStatus FROM TblReg INNER JOIN TblRegjoin ON TblReg.Filenum = TblRegjoin.PrtFilenum WHERE (TblRegjoin.PtFilenum = 15090248) ORDER BY TblRegjoin.PrtFilenum")
            cmd.Connection = con
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                sda.Fill(ds, "PtPrt")
            End Using
            Return ds.GetXml()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: `Using cmd As New SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con)` followed by `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` may solve your issue.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer instead of a comment so i can mark it,,,, it worked,,, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
<WebMethod> _
    Public Function GetPtPrt() As String
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ARTSQLConStrng").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("ProcedureName", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Connection = con
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    sda.Fill(ds, "PtPrt")
                End Using
                Return ds.GetXml()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Hope it helps.